# add a new document in a collection in firestore using flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a shopping/selling  kind of application. There I want to add my list of products to a collection named books whenever any seller adds his product. I wrote

```
     Firestore.instance.collection('books').add({
         'title':b.title,    //b is an argument I got in the method
     });
```

but when I run it, no collection is added in the Firestore. 
What to do?
the console comes till here and then nothing happens:

E/flutter (15848): #28     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:275:10)
E/flutter (15848): #29     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:184:5)
E/flutter (15848):

Comment: Is there an exception being thrown? Can you add a .then/.catch and see if the promise resolves or throws an exception (log the output then...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a document with random id, keep the id inside document empty

```
   Firestore.instance.collection('books').document().setData({
         'title':b.title,    //b is an argument I got in the method
     });
```

If you want to add document with specific ID, put the ID inside document():

```
   Firestore.instance.collection('books').document("docId").setData({
         'title':b.title,    //b is an argument I got in the method
     });
```

Comment: Check if there is any exception thrown, also u did connect the database correctly right?

Comment: Yes database is connected correctly as when i log in with a new user...that user is correctly created

Comment: no error is coming. Its just that the collection is not created when this code runs. The last line on the console is --->  _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:184:5) E/flutter (15848): and after this no further line is coming on the console.

Comment: As mentioned on the comment, it might be worth using .then/.catch and see if the promise resolves or throws an exception. This will give us more info on the error

Comment: my problem is solved. Actually the database rules I wrote were blocking some permissions that is why the collection was not being created. Thanks

Comment: @MehakSinghal if the problem was with the permission please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem where with rules of I wrote for Firestone. I simply put too many restrictions so my user was not getting permission to write in the database.
Then I erased what I wrote and set the rules to default what they were written at
the start.